# Programmatically edit file names to remove leading text

Tags: powershell, texttrimming

I have a variety of files with names in the directory that look like this:

```
first_file_123456.jpg
5 * second_file_246531 (2).jpg
```

What I am looking to do is lay my hands on a PowerShell script that can take these files and rename them like this:

```
123456.jpg
246531 (2).jpg
```

I am looking to strip the last underscore and all text leading up to it to rename my files so they can match item numbers in my enterprise resource planning system. This system is much older (2004 technology) so automating from that side is out.

What i have tried to wire up so far and does not seem to work properly is as follows:

```
    Get-ChildItem -Recurse -filter *_*  | `
    Foreach-Object {
    $oldName = $_.Name
    $pos = $oldName.LastIndexOf("_")
    $newName = $oldName.Substring($pos + 1)
    if (Test-Path $newName) {
        # This is where I get lost - if it runs into a duplicate file name
        # how can I make the name unique
    }        
    #write-host $_.fullname
    write-host $oldName renamed To: $newName | Out-File renamelog.txt
    #rename-item $_.FullName -NewName $newName
}
```

I commented out the commands that actually do something to see what the output is.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: Having said that, I commend to your attention the [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-5.1).

Comment: Look at string "LastIndexOf" and substrings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enumerate your files, filter for filenames containing an underscore, then rename them with everything up to and including the last underscore removed.

```
$re = '^.*_'

Get-ChildItem 'C:\some\folder' |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match $re } |
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace $re }
```

Comment: Ok, thank you Ansgar et al. Now, how can we expand this PS command to handle duplicate file names by say appending the name with a letter. Say file 123456.jpg exists, the renamed file I would like to name 123456 (1).jpg and so on. Doable?

Comment: @bbcompent1 Please do not move the target. If you have a new or followup question: post a new question. However, similar questions have been asked before, so please do some research and try to get it to work yourself first.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short demo that uses the `LastIndexOf` and `Substring` methods:

```
$name = "first_file_123456.jpg"
$indexOfLastUnderscore = $name.LastIndexOf("_")
$newName = $name.Substring($indexOfLastUnderscore + 1, $name.Length - $indexOfLastUnderscore - 1)
# $newName now contains "123456.jpg"
```

Here's another way that uses PowerShell's `-split` operator and array indexing:

```
$name = "first_file_123456.jpg"
$newName = ($name -split '_')[-1]
$newName
# $newName now contains "123456.jpg"
```

Answer (score 1):

Batch rename:

```
Get-Childitem -path $startDir -recurse |
    where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } |
    foreach { 
        $newName = Join-Path $_.Directory  ($_.Name -replace '.*_', '');
        Rename-Item $_.FullName $newName;
    };
```

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Path $Dir -Recurse -File | Rename-Item -NewName ($_.Name -replace '.*_')`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - That's **_assuming_** one has access to a PowerShell version **greater** than 2.0, which did **not** have the `-file` parameter.... ;).

Comment: Sure, but this is 2018. It's unusual to *not* have a greater WMF version installed or to be migrating to W10/12+ by now.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - uh, no - I work for [the largest employer](http://www.bnd.com/living/article79507112.html) in the US, and sorry to say that's not the case....

Comment: Walmart? Sorry to hear that.

Comment: Large organizations typically have a tight change-control process that requires a substantial justification for making system-level changes, so this is not really all that surprising.

Comment: To clarify, at that point in time I was working in a very limited environment with infrastructure elements from the early 2000's. My Powershell was at version 1 so I was completely baffled as to how to make this work. I thank all of you for your assistance. I just had no idea what to do at that point.